# Redefine tomcat mapping for directory in webapps

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Basically I am trying to configure `Tomcat 7` so it would serve under a certain folder from `webapps` under another path.

The example project structure:

```
webapp/
   someFolder/
      content.html
```

current mapping: `http://localhost:8082/someFolder/content.html`

desired mapping: `http://localhost:8082/some/content.html`

and additionally I would like the `http://localhost:8082/someFolder/` path not to be available anymore.

How to achieve that?
All the resources are static files and I know it could be better achieved using proxy but I have to stick to Tomcat atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the simplest option is to rename "someFolder" to "some". Anything else is fighting against the way that deployment is designed to work in Tomcat.

If you *really* need to do this then you'll have to disable all the automatic deployment options for the host and define all the Contexts manually in server.xml. This approach is a lot more hassle and is not recommended.